# Export the display of a Windows Container in Docker for GUI testing

Tags: windows, docker, docker-for-windows

I know that it is possible to connect to a remote Unix machine by running an X Server on Windows and exporting the Unix display to that server. By passing in an environment variable with the docker run command (`-e DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0`), I am able to run Unix GUI applications from within a docker container on a Windows computer. I primarily learned about this from [this article on Medium](https://medium.com/better-programming/running-desktop-apps-in-docker-43a70a5265c4).

I've encountered a number of blog posts, some from Microsoft and some external, that discuss the potential for GUI testing Windows applications using the new `windows` container. Is there a clean way to export the display of an application from within a `windows` container? Is there some way to run an X11 client on Windows that you can connect to from another Windows computer? Is there an alternative that could be used to accomplish this?